# get value of child <div> of a parent <div>

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        some-value
    </div>
</div>
```

how do I get "some-value"?
I tried

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var child = parent.childNodes[0];
var childval = child.value;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=childval;
```

it outputs "undefined".

Comment: Please try to get familiar with reading references. For example the [DOM Reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference) is a great resource. You will see that a div (`HTMLDivElement`) has no `value` property. You will also find what you can actually use.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `value` property only exists for form elements. If you want to get the content of any other elements, you can either use [`innerHTML` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML) to get the content as HTML string, or [`textContent` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) resp. [`innerText` *<sup>[MSDN]</sup>*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to only get the text content without HTML tags.

[`childNodes` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/childNodes) returns *all* child nodes, not only element nodes. That means, it also contains *text nodes* for example. The line break you have after `<div id="parent">` is a text node as well. Hence, `parent.childNodes[0]` returns the text node which consists only of a line break.

If you want to get the first element node, you can either use [`children`  *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.children) (see [browser compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t71)), or iterate over the child nodes, testing what kind of node each of them is. `1` indicates an element node, `3` a text node:

```
var child = parent.firstChild;

while(child && child.nodeType !== 1) {
    child = child.nextSibling;
}
```

There are also other ways to retrieve elements, e.g. with [`getElementsByTagName` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).

Or in your case, you can just use [`getElementById` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.getElementById) to get a reference to both of the elements.

Comment: "Hence, parent.childNodes[0] returns the text node which consists only of a line break." <<< THANK YOU!!!! And thanks for the references, google is becoming a spam collector, all I kept getting was links to various unanswered/irrelevant questions.

Comment: MDN has great documentation. Just add `mdn` as keyword when you search for something DOM or JavaScript related.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that `parent` `<div>` actuially has three children: a `TextNode` containing a new line after `parent` opening tag, the actual `child` `<div>` and yet another `TextNode` with newline after closing `child` tag. But hard-coding second item is a bad idea:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
console.info(parent.childNodes.length);
var child = parent.childNodes[1];
var childval = child.innerHTML;
```

I would suggest iterating over children and finding the actual `child` or using

```
parent.getElementsByTagName('div')
```

shorthand.

That's one of the reasons why people love jQuery so much:

```
$('#parent div').text()
```

Comment: Yes, best is to use actual getElementById("child")... but purpose was to actually learn the DOM. Iterating and finding the actual child sounds better approach than mine. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can also use `document.querySelector('#parent div')` if you want to avoid jQuery

Answer (score 6):

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var child = parent.children[0];
var childVal = child.innerHTML;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = childVal;
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/bcqVC/2/

Comment: um... I changed it to parent.childNodes[1] and it worked (as Felix said above). I overlooked that you used .children[0] which works too. Thanks.

Comment: @gion_13 works for me thanks

Answer (score 3):

**document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = document.getElementById("child").innerHTML;**

This will solve your problem.

Using your way of approach try as shown below

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var child = parent.childNodes[0];
```

**var childval = child.innerHTML;**

```
document.getElementById("outPut").innerHTML=childval;
```

This will also solve your problem

Comment: yeah no, but I really need to use the child property here. Is that not possible?

Comment: `parent.childNodes[0]` does not refer to the element node.

Answer (score 2):

To get all the `<div>` elements you can use:

```
var div_val=prompt("Enter a div to Get the Child Elements","");
var div_ele=document.getElementById(div_val).childNodes;
for (var i=0, max=div_ele.length; i < max; i++) {
    alert(div_ele[i]); //All your Div Elements
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this way by this pointer.**

```js
var childs = document.getElementById('myDropdown').children; //returns a HTMLCollection

for (var indx = 0; indx < childs.length; indx++) {
    // iterate over it
    childs[indx].onclick = function() {
        // attach event listener On Symbole Dive THIS . 
        this.style.color = "#ff0000";
        // add to note form the symbole .
        document.getElementById("Note_form").value += this.innerHTML;


    }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
     
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <div>♥</div>
                <div>☺</div>
                <div>π</div>
                <div>•</div>
                <div>Σ</div>
                <div>°</div>
                <div>Ω</div>
                <div>∞</div>
                <div>×</div>
                <div>÷</div>
                <div>≥</div>
                <div>≤</div>
                <div>≠</div>
                <div>®</div>
                <div>©</div>
                <div>¥</div>
                <div>£</div>
                <div>€</div>
             
            </div>
        </div>
        
          <textarea id="Note_form" class="copy_erea" placeholder="The Content.." oninput="note_Edite(this.value);"></textarea>
```