# Access child element value of Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code:

```
<div class="dataTables_filter" id="searchResult_filter">
  <label>Text: 
       <input type="text" aria-controls="searchResult">
 </label>
</div>
```

I want to get the input field values if anything is entered.

I only have mentioned code and i can't change it like putting id or adding any event. So then how to do it.

Even if i'm able to detect changes in div that will also helpful.

I have tried like:

```
$("#searchResult_filter").change(function() {
  alert("ketyup");
});
```

Comment: Attach a `keyup` or `keypress` event handler to the `input`

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769158/get-value-of-child-div-of-a-parent-div

Comment: How to attatch keyup  for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution: By adding keyup eventListener

```
document.getElementById("searchResult_filter").addEventListener("keyup",disableConsultarOpcionesdeFinanciacion);
```

It call the below function on input box keyup:

```
function disableConsultarOpcionesdeFinanciacion()
{
 //Code to do somthing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**.keyup()**](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

> **Description**: Bind an event handler to the "keyup" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

```
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function (e) {


        alert($(this).val());

    });
```

Comment: I don't have any id for input field.

Comment: @Abhay Ok select using above changed method

Comment: I have multiple input fields in my html.

Comment: Then either select using id , or their index values . Actually above code will  work for all input type text .. and it will give you the value of input being changed real time. @Abhay

Comment: I only have mentioned code and i can't change it like putting id or something. So then how to do it.

Comment: @Abhay : use above code it will work for multiple text input too

Comment: In that case if i enter in other input then function will execute.

Comment: if you change any text input ,, this function will run and give the value of that particular text input

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<div class="dataTables_filter" id="searchResult_filter">
 <label>Text: 
    <input type="text" aria-controls="searchResult"   onchange="GetInputVal(value)">
  </label>
</div>

 function GetInputVal(val) {  
 //your logic to handle the value
 }
```

Comment: I have not access to add onchange method can it be possible to add it via js/jquery?

Comment: pls try $( "input[aria-controls="searchResult").change(function() { // your logic here}

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selector also work like the css selector. So you can use the following code.

```
$("#searchResult_filter input[type=text]").keyup(function (e) {
        console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Or

```
$("input[aria-controls=searchResult]").keyup(function (e) {
            console.log($(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: I have posted the solution.