# Edit function for to do list

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a homework to do list application based in HTML and Javascript. I am currently trying to implement an edit function but cannot figure out how to call a div tag within a child element. The edit function needs to be able to copy the contents displayed in the  tag into the text area.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Homework</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Homework Tracker</h1>
    <br>
    <div class="AddNewSub"> <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:30px;  vertical-align: middle;">receipt</i>
        <textarea id="addhw" placeholder="Input Homework"></textarea>
        <button type="button" id="addbutton" onclick="add()"> Add </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="MainContents"> </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("MainContents").innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('UserInputCon')); 

        function add() {
            var contents = document.getElementById('addhw').value;
            contents = contents.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
            var newline = document.createElement('div');
            newline.setAttribute("class", "close");
            newline.setAttribute("id", "UserConDiv")
            newline.innerHTML = "<div id='contentdiv'>" + contents + "</div>" + " " + "<button type='button' id='delbutton' onclick='deletehw(this)'>Delete</button>" + "<button type='button' id='delbutton' onclick='edithw(this)'>Edit</button>" + "<br>";
            document.getElementById("MainContents").appendChild(newline);
            localStorage.setItem('UserInputCon', JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("MainContents").innerHTML));


        }

        function deletehw(element) {

            let container = element.parentElement;
            container.parentNode.removeChild(container);
            localStorage.removeItem('UserInputCon');
            localStorage.setItem('UserInputCon', JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("MainContents").innerHTML));
        }

        function edithw(element) {
            var conDiv = document.getElementById('contentdiv').innerHTML;
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < conDiv.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById('addhw').value = conDiv[i].innerHTML;
                var container = element.parentElement;
            container.parentNode.removeChild(container);
            localStorage.removeItem('UserInputCon');
            localStorage.setItem('UserInputCon', JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("MainContents").innerHTML));

            }           
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you `edithw` function ***could*** be:

```
function edithw(element) 
{         
    let text = element.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML
    document.getElementById('addhw').value = text;
}
```

What you are missing in your `edithw` function is needing to get the innerHtml from a div that was within the generated parent div.

You don't need to worry about looping over anything, since you already have the parent element of the data you want.

`element.parentElement` gets your the parent div, [but you cannot call `getElementById` from a `parentElement`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8769219/1427427), instead use `getElementsByTagName`, then get the innerHtml of whatever child you want, in this case it was the first element.

You can `console.log()` it out as you go to see what you get from each call to make it easier to understand:

```
    function edithw(element) 
    {         
        console.log('element',element);
        console.log('element.parentElement',element.parentElement);
        console.log('element.parentElement.getElementsByTagName',element.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('div'));

        let text = element.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML
        document.getElementById('addhw').value = text;

    }
```

Here is the full code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Homework</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Homework Tracker</h1>
<br>
<div class="AddNewSub"> <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:30px;  vertical-align: middle;">receipt</i>
  <textarea id="addhw" placeholder="Input Homework"></textarea>
  <button type="button" id="addbutton" onclick="add()"> Add </button>
</div>
<br>
<div id="MainContents"> </div>
<script>

        document.getElementById("MainContents").innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('UserInputCon')); 

        function add() {

            var contents = document.getElementById('addhw').value;
            contents = contents.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');

            var newline = document.createElement('div');
            newline.setAttribute("class", "close");
            newline.setAttribute("id", "UserConDiv")
            newline.innerHTML =  
                "<div id='contentdiv'>" + 
                contents + 
                "</div>" + 
                " " + 
                "<button type='button' id='delbutton' onclick='deletehw(this)'>Delete</button>" + 
                "<button type='button' id='editbutton' onclick='edithw(this)'>Edit</button>" + 
                "<br>";

            document.getElementById("MainContents").appendChild(newline);
            localStorage.setItem('UserInputCon', JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("MainContents").innerHTML));
        }

        function deletehw(element) {
            let container = element.parentElement;
            container.parentNode.removeChild(container);
            localStorage.removeItem('UserInputCon');
            localStorage.setItem('UserInputCon', JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("MainContents").innerHTML));
        }

        function edithw(element) 
        {         
            console.log('element',element);
            console.log('element.parentElement',element.parentElement);
            console.log('element.parentElement.getElementsByTagName',element.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('div'));
            
            let text = element.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML
            document.getElementById('addhw').value = text;

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! The solution works, however, when the edited text is displayed in the text area, it shows the breaks. Is it possible to remove this?